# How to find the name of a graph in Galaxybase using the PAR API?

Tags: graph-databases

I'm using PAR (Parameterized Algorithm Routine) API in Galaxybase. I can't find the instructions on how to find the name of a graph in the technical documentation. I've tried `getGraphName()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:  `graph.meta().getGraphName()`